# How can I prevent 2nd desktop from going to sleep

Tags: suspend

Because I need a fullscreen application I made a new desktop in xsessions called GUI.desktop.

Upon booting this desktop launches the application via a shellscript and when I quit the app, the desktop logs of automatically.

I cannot use the terminal or the system settings. I do can open them via the start shellscript but they lie below the application and I can't use them. When I only launch the terminal, the desktop logs of near instantaneous.

I either need to know in which file the system settings are stored so I can modify it or I need to prevent the desktop from logging off automatically so I can use the system settings.

EDIT: I could open the system settings and I changed the go to sleep time to 'never' but the panel PC still goes to sleep and I don't know why

Comment: i know this might not be ideal, but if it's your monitor that sleeps too early, you might be able to use a software that randomly moves pixels around on that monitor.

Comment: That does not work I'm afraid. I have an Arduino board sending instructions to the machine al the time and those instructions let a dot dance arround